# How to remove image view class in css

Tags: html, css

**php**

```
 <a href='.$row5['url'].'"><img src="../asset/view-as-pdf.jpg"
 width="94" height="94" /></a>
```

**html**

```
<center>
   <a href="http://tools.com/com/fli7ppdf/K171/157/Kap157_E/files/kap157_en.pdf&quot;">
     <img src="asset/view-as-pdf.jpg" height="94" width="94" />
   </a>
</center>
```

after click image, it not open url, but view image. how to fix it

Comment: Have you tried to put `img` tag inside `ancho`r tag ?

Comment: It seems you forgot to add the source code.

Comment: i think other related css make this image view in new tab

Answer (score 0):

```
<center><a
 href="http://kstools.com/com/flippdf/K11/15/Kap15_E/files/kap15_en.pdf&quot;"><a
 target="_blank" href="asset/view-as-pdf.jpg"><img
 src="asset/view-as-pdf.jpg" height="94" width="94"></a></a></center>
```

Here you are closing `a` twice.

Your code should like this ,

```
   <center><a href="http://kstools.com/com/flippdf/K11/15/Kap15_E/files/kap15_en.pdf&quot;"><img src="asset/view-as-pdf.jpg" height="94" width="94"></a></center>
```

Comment: Yes, Fledgling is right, anchor tag close twice. remove anyone.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<center>
 <a href="http://kstools.com/com/flippdf/K11/15/Kap15_E/files/kap15_en.pdf&quot;">
   <img src="asset/view-as-pdf.jpg" height="94" width="94" />
 </a>
</center>
```

Remove `anchor tag` which has link of the image.